# Filter output in logcat by tagname

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I'm trying to filter logcat output from a real device (not an emulator) by tag name but I get all the messages which is quite a spam. I just want to read messages from browser which should be something like "browser:*" or "webkit:*" , but it doesn't work...
Here it is what I get:

[image: actual output]

Answer (score 341, accepted):

use this:

```
adb logcat -s "TAGNAME"
```

Comment: Thank you! 
The above is equivalent to 
adb logcat *:s 'tagname'

Comment: How can I filter OUT a <tagname> ?

Comment: I believe the only way to filter out is by levels. For example, if some app is spamming Debug then set the logcat level to only show Info and higher levels: logcat *:I

Comment: for all the levels, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat

Comment: For multiple connected devices : adb -s "DeviceId" logcat -s "TagName"

Comment: You can also do this with the ANDROID_LOG_TAGS environment variable, which is useful if you always use a certain filter.

Comment: Is it possible to use above with -f filename? Say, my scenario is to filter the logs by TagName and dump to a text file.

Comment: Das - "adb logcat TAGNAME:s" will 's'ilence a noisy tag.

Comment: A novice question: What does TAG refer to? I have a small Java program that I build a module out of, and this serves as an Android plug-in for another application. I just wanna see a particular function in it is called, so I put a `System.out.println("camera focus set");` in the body of the function. Where am I supposed to see this message? What would be my TAG if I wanted to use `adb logcat` at the terminal?

Answer (score 73):

In case someone stumbles in on this like I did, you can filter on multiple tags by adding a comma in between, like so:

```
adb logcat -s "browser","webkit"
```

Comment: Explain where should i put this code. I am a new bee . Please Explain

Comment: @Nepster Type that in the terminal.

Comment: If you use cygwin on windows, you can use grep...and yes, this works.

Answer (score 16):

Another option is setting the log levels for specific tags:

```
adb logcat SensorService:S PowerManagerService:S NfcService:S power:I Sensors:E
```

If you just want to set the log levels for some tags you can do it on a tag by tag basis.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I create a tag:

```
private static final String TAG = SomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 Log.d(TAG, "some description");
```

You could use getCannonicalName

Here I have following TAG filters:

- any (*) View - VERBOSE
- any (*) Activity - VERBOSE
- any tag starting with Xyz(*) - ERROR
- System.out - SILENT (since I am using Log in my own code)

Here what I type in terminal:

```
$  adb logcat *View:V *Activity:V Xyz*:E System.out:S
```

Answer (score 9):

Do not depend on ADB shell, just treat it (the adb logcat) a normal linux output and then pip it:

```
$ adb shell logcat | grep YouTag
# just like: 
$ ps -ef | grep your_proc
```

Comment: This is a bad choice because a lot of unnecessary traffic is sent, and the filter obviously won't work. If an unrelated process logs message that happens to have some string in it would appear.

Comment: `and the filter obviously won't work`,   have you tried?  I have, and pasted my answer according to the result.

Comment: The question was for windows, where grep is not available

Comment: If you use cygwin on windows, you can use grep...and yes, this works.