# How can I filter OUT a <tagname> using adb logcat

Tags: android

This is related to [Filter output in logcat by tagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173985/filter-output-in-logcat-by-tagname). How can I filter out a tagname. Ex - If I don't want the tagname GNU.IO to be echoed to stdout, I would like something which would do the equivalent of -

```
adb logcat | grep -v <tagname>
```

Unfortunately the above is not working for me.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. The above works but if someone knows of a way to filter out a tagname natively with logcat, i.e. without piping to grep, please do post an answer answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

logcat won't do it for you, but if you want the device to do the work, you could use `adb shell`:

```
adb shell 'logcat | grep -v <tagname>'
```

Comment: filter *out* as in remove

Answer (score 4):

I found that this works well for what I wanted -

adb logcat -s TAG:V

Answer (score 0):

Just set specific tag's level to S(ilent):

```
adb logcat <TAG>:S
```

as result, you'll see all messages excluding TAG