# BounceScrollRunnableDefault is being spammed in the LogCat

Tags: android, scrollview, logcat, android-overscoll

Whenever I run my application and try to over-scroll in a `ScrollView` my LogCat is being spammed with over 50 entries all saying a similar thing:

`run(), TimeFraction=0.785, mBounceExtent=31.378126`

All with the tag: `BounceScrollRunnableDefault`

Only the numbers change a bit each entry.

In the `ScrollView` I have set `overScrollMode` to `never`.

Does all this debug-output slow down the app? And is there a way to prevent/suppress this big wall of output?

Note: The reason I've set the overScrollMode to never is because I didn't want the blue-ish overscroll glow that Android generates.

Comment: FWIW, `BounceScrollRunnableDefault` does not appear to be part of Android. It probably was added by a device manufacturer, and therefore would only affect a handful of devices.

Comment: My test device is: Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 , I guess there's no way around it then. Not really that bad, but it makes debugging trough the LogCat a bit harder.

Comment: You can filter logcat by tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173985/filter-output-in-logcat-by-tagname