# adb filter by tag does not work in Windows command prompt

Tags: android, windows, adb, adt, command-prompt

The following:

```
adb -s phoneserialnumber logcat *:D
```

and the following both output ALL logs, not just "Debug" logs, not to mention "Debug" logs that has tag "MyDebugTag"

```
adb -s phoneserialnumber logcat MyDebugTag:D
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried -s is the switch for setting filtering spec to silent by default?
    `logcat -s <tag>:<level>`

There are lot's of questions like this one on SO already. [Filter output in logcat by tagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173985/filter-output-in-logcat-by-tagname?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @QuentinSwain. adding `*:S` at the end of the command has the same effect too. It is actually describe in [Google's documentaiton](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) though confusing. I mean one already include the tag name and the priority there which are sufficient for filtering, what help does the "silent" thing offer - unless you tell me that's the way it is and I just have to put up with it?