# adb logcat specific app only

Tags: android, cordova, adb

When I run `adb logcat`, I will get the extreme fast moving list of data in the console window. This make it very hard to trace log the app I want to debug. How can I have `adb logcat` only display info of the app I want to debug?

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173985/filter-output-in-logcat-by-tagname). Let me know if everything worked great.

Comment: I think you are searching for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6854182/2101822

Comment: @Milad Thanks for the link. But the answer provided is very confusing.

Comment: just set a tag name for your logs then filter all logs with that tag like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18012001/2101822

Comment: `adb shell logcat | grep "something related to your app"`