# View exceptions which had happened before connecting ADB

Tags: android, android-logcat

While I am test-driving my unpublished application on my physical device without connecting it to a computer, sometimes an exception happens and the application gets killed. Now, if I connect the device to my computer and launch Android Studio and connect the Android monitor, the logcat does not show the exception that happened before connecting the device, and the exception is not reproducible.

Is there any way to make the device keep logs so that I can check it later with Android Studio?

Comment: When that happens I connect the device quickly, open up a terminal window, and type `adb logcat -v time`.  It will usually get the last 10 minutes or so of all logs from the device.  You will need to sift through all the logs to find where your app crashed, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Can I filter the logs to see only the logs from my application?

Comment: For filtering on log contents, I do `adb logcat -v time | egrep 'search_string'`, for filtering on the tag, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173985/filter-output-in-logcat-by-tagname

Answer (score 0):

Check this out : https://github.com/gaozp/ErrorHandleDemo ;

or you can check out this : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html;

BTW this means you should implement a handler to catch all exception that your app occurs . and when your app has hit a exception ,this handler will catch this ,and you can save it to a time-named log to record this exception.