# Getting adb logs on PC using a batch file while the Android app is running

Tags: android, adb, android-logcat

I have a created a windows batch file(log.bat) like this below :

```
adb logcat -c
adb logcat -d > log.txt
```

But it soon exits whenever I press log.bat command.

I want it to keep recording the logs unless I press ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html#Syntax)

> -c : Clears (flushes) the entire log and exits.
>
> -d : Dumps the log to the screen and exits.

So, in both cases, the execution stops once you run the logcat command with these options. Try this,

```
adb logcat -c && adb logcat > log.txt
```

This won't let the shell execution to be released once it executes `logcat -c` and will start the next command right after it which is `adb logcat > log.txt` that is going to write the logcat's log till you hit the Ctrl + c.

Comment: Thanks it worked.How can I get the logs for a particular tags like D/BatteryService && E/Watchdog && V/MyAPP ..Is there any rule which I can create or additionaly put in the command you posted?

Comment: I didn't try this out by myself but I think this will help you find what you're seeking.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173985/filter-output-in-logcat-by-tagname

Answer (score 1):

It looks problem is using option -d with logcat. Please check usage :

-d              Dump the log and then exit (don't block)

Removing it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

I need to create a batch file that can copy a log file to a PC. The batch file I created doesn't work. When I run all the commands manually it works however when putting into a script it hangs. Here are the individual commands:

Try this single line command:

```
$adb shell run-as com.example.name cat /data/data/com.example.name/files/logfile.log > c:\logs\logfile.log
```