# Adb logcat display only OkHttp calls

Tags: shell, android-studio, adb, logcat

[image]

On android studio you can filter OkHttp calls.
Is there a command that allows you to do this from the shell?

`adb logcat ...`

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: I assume the term `OkHttp` is the TAG of the logcat messages. If that is true you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6174001/150978

Comment: @Robert: It seems that this is not it.